# Residue of $f(z)=\frac{z}{\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{z+1}\right)}}$ in all isolated singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I have this complex function:
$$f(z)=\frac{z}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{z+1}\right)}$$
I'd like to compute residues in all isolate singularities.
If I'm not mistaken $f$ has poles in $z=\frac{1}{k}-1$ and a non isolated singularity in $z=-1$, because it is an accumulation point of poles.
I tried to do something similar to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1645556/228483), but I don't seem to get a clean expression in terms of $\xi$, where $\xi$ is $z-\frac{1}{k}+1$.
The best I can obtain is this:

$$\frac{z}{\sin\left(\frac{k\xi+1-k}{k\xi+1}\right)}$$

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\sin\left(\frac\pi{z+1}\right)$. Then$$f'(z)=-\frac{\pi\cos\left(\frac\pi{z+1}\right)}{(z+1)^2}$$and therefore$$f'\left(\frac1k-1\right)=(-1)^{k-1}k^2\pi.$$So,$$\operatorname{res}_{z=\frac1k-1}\left(\frac z{\sin\left(\frac\pi{z+1}\right)}\right)=\frac{\frac1k-1}{(-1)^{k-1}k^2\pi}=(-1)^{k-1}\frac{1-k}{k^3\pi}.$$

Comment: thank you, but i don't understand the last equality; why is the residue equal to $\frac{\frac{1}{k}-1}{f^{'}(\frac{1}{k}-1)}$?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are analytic functions, $f(z_0)\neq0$, and $z_0$ is a simple pole of $g$, then$$\operatorname{res}_{z=z_0}\left(\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right)=\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}.$$

Comment: @EugenioDiPaola For completeness, you should include the residue at $z = \infty$, which is $\pi/6$. The sum of all residues will be zero (if we choose smaller and smaller circles around $z = -1$ between the poles, the sequence of integrals tends to zero).

Comment: right, i forgot about that :) That's interesting, my course material states: "if a function has ONLY isolated singularities the sum of all residues, taken in account also the eventual residue at infinity, is zero".
You're saying that the integral that contains only -1 inside and all the isolated singularities outside is zero.
So, is there a stronger statement such as "the sum of all residues of isolated singularities is zero", even if the function has not isolated singularities? Or we're just lucky for this particular function?

Comment: My guess is that you were just lucky with this particular function.

Comment: WolphramAlpha says the residue is $-\pi/6$, not $\pi/6$ ;). What am I doing wrong with the limit of that sequence of integrals?:
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}{\oint_{C_{\frac{1}{|k|}+\epsilon}}\frac{z}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{z+1})}dz}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}{2\pi i \left[-\frac{\pi}{6}+\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac{1-n}{n^3\pi}+\sum_{n=-(k-1)}^{-1}\frac{1-n}{n^3\pi}\right]}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}{2\pi i \left[-\frac{\pi}{6}+\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac{-2}{n^2\pi}\right]}=2\pi i\left(-\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$$

Comment: @EugenioDiPaola Just compute the residue yourself (though it is rather cumbersome). And don't forget the $(-1)^n$ factor in the sums. We can't take a contour that contains only the accumulation point inside, but we can talk about a sequence of contours. If you have a combination of trigs and powers and the sum of residues converges, you should expect it to converge to zero.